# Problems with copying at file structure by using xcopy

Tags: windows, xcopy, file-structure

I have tried to copy the file the file structure from an old disc to a new one without copying the files. I have used the command xcopy E:\Richard\Documents C:\Users\Documents /T /E /Q and got the question whether C:\Users\Documents is a file or a directory, answered "directory" and got the answer Access denied. Why? Is it something with the attributes of C?
Can I improve the command in some way?
Something outsida the command that I should do?

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming

Comment: Are there anything you can recommend me to do?